# Vim - sort the contents of a register before/after pasting it?

Tags: vim

As part of a project of mine I'm trying to move certain lines from a file to the top, sorted in a certain fashion. I'm not sure how to do the sort once those lines are up there - I don't want to disturb the other lines in the file.

I'm moving them by yanking them and putting them back down, like so:

```
g:/pattern/yank A
g:/pattern/d
0put A
```

This moves all the lines I specify up to the top of the file like I need, but now I need to sort them according to a pattern, like so:

```
[range]sort r /pattern2/
```

Is there a way to sort the contents of a register before pasting it? Or a way to sort only lines which match /pattern/? (because all the yanked lines will, of course).

I'm stymied and help would be appreciated.

edit - a possible workaround might be to count the number of lines before they're yanked, and then use that to select and sort those lines once they're placed again. I'm not sure how to count those lines - I can print the number of lines that match a pattern with the command :%s/pattern//n but I can't do anything with that number, or use that in a function.

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of `:g/pattern/cmd` is to execute `cmd` on every line matching `pattern`. `cmd` can, of course, be `:sort`.

In the same way you did:

```
:g/pattern/yank A
```

to append every line matching `pattern` to register `a` and:

```
:g/pattern/d
```

to cut every line matching `pattern`, you can do:

```
:g/pattern/sort r /pattern2/
```

to sort every line matching `pattern` on `pattern2`.

Your example is wasteful anyway. Instead of abusing registers with three commands you could simply do:

```
:g/pattern/m0
```

to move every line matching `pattern` to the top of the buffer before sorting them with:

```
:g//sort r /pattern2/
```

See `:help :global`, `:help :sort`, `:help :move`.

Comment: `:g/pattern/sort`: That's doesn't do what you think it does. `:sort`'s default range is the entire buffer; the `:global` is ineffective. If you use `:.sort` instead, individual lines will be sorted, so a no-op. You really need a single range of consecutive lines for `:sort` to work, unfortunately.

Comment: @romainl Thank you for your help, but I'm not sure this does what I need it to do - If I use :g//sort r /pattern/ then it runs the sort command on one line at a time, effectively doing nothing. If I use :sort r /pattern/, it sorts every line in the document - something I have to avoid. The only way I can think of is to pull the lines I need into a register, put them back down, and then sort them. The problem however is i know of no way to sort the contents of a register.

Comment: One possible solution would be to count the lines to be moved, then put them at the top, then sort that range. I'm not sure how to get the number of lines which match a pattern. :substitute with the n tag can *print* the number of lines which match a pattern, but I can't then do anything with that value.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, and may not be of any use to you anymore, but I just figured this one out today.  It relies on the system's `sort` command (not vim's).  Assuming you're saving to register A:

```
qaq
:g/pattern/yank A
<C-O>
:put=system('sort --stable --key=2,3',@A)
```

`qaq`: clears register A of anything

`:g/pattern/yank A`: searches current buffer for pattern and copies it to register A

`<C-O>`: pressing Ctrl+O in normal mode returns you to the last place your cursor was

`:put=system('sort --stable --key=2,3',@A)`: sends the contents of register A to the sort command's STDIN and pastes the output to the current position of the cursor.

I mapped this whole thing to `<F8>`:

```
noremap <F8> qaq:g/pattern/yank A<CR><C-O>:put=system('sort --stable --key=2,3',@A)<CR>
```

I don't know how janky this is considered, cuz I'm a complete noob to vim.  I spent hours today trying to figure this out. It works for me and I'm happy with it, hopefully it'll help someone else too.